# Append string to char array

Tags: c

I have a code with a character array as follows:

```
int main (int argc, char** argv)
{
   char arr[] = "%55u%10$n";
   return 0;
}
```

I wish to dynamically set `10` through a string input from the user, for example `argv[1]`.

What would the correct syntax of the following be:

```
char arr[] = "%55u%" argv[2] "$n"; // which would basically be "%55u%10$n" if argv[1] == "10"
```

Comment: That's not the *number 10*. That's the two characters `'1'` and `'0'`.

Comment: @KenWhite Apologies. Corrected it.

Comment: You cannot rely on concatenation of string literals with a variable not known until runtime. The compiler has no idea what `argv[1]` is going to be. See Remy's answer or use `strcat`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `sprintf()`:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main (int argc, char** argv)
{
   if (argc > 1)
   {
      char arr[20];
      sprintf(arr, "%%55u%%%.12s$n", argv[1]);
      ...
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Alternatively, use `strcpy()` and `strcat()` (use with care!):

```c
#include <string.h>

int main (int argc, char** argv)
{
   if (argc > 1)
   {
      char arr[20];
      strcpy(arr, "%55u%");
      strcat(arr, argv[1]);
      // or: strcat_s(arr, sizeof(arr)-3, argv[1]);
      strcat(arr, "$n");
      ...
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `sprintf`. Be sure to escape literal `%` characters and ensure your buffer is large enough to hold the result string.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    if (argc < 2) { return 0; }

    char arr[strlen(argv[1])+8];
    sprintf(arr, "%%55u%%%s$n", argv[1]);
    printf("%s\n", arr);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Using a [VLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) may not be the best option though

Comment: Maybe not, but it depends on the use case. Hardcoding 20 might not be the best option, either. Can you elaborate? If a huge input is provided, the stack frame will blow up--would this be a security risk?

Comment: I hard-coded 20 in my example because I originally used `%d` for `sprintf()`, and the max value for a 32-bit integer is 10 digits. Then I saw the OP's desire to use `argv` for user input,so I switched my example to `%s` instead, but 20 is a good limit unless the OP needs more digits

Comment: Although OP chose `"10"`, it's not entirely clear that they want to limit input to digits otherwise, and there's nothing preventing the user from providing some non-integer string as it stands.

Comment: @ggorlen what about dynamically allocating memory?

Comment: Sure, that's fine too.